# Dependency Injection in java

Tags: java, dependency-injection, javax-inject

I was trying dependency injection in java using the @Inject annotation and I was following the tutorial in this [link](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/java-ee-cdi-dependency-injection-inject-tutorial.html). According to the tutorial I created the following.

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class GreetingBean {


@Inject private static HelloBean helloBean;

//  @Inject
//    public GreetingBean(HelloBean helloBean){
//      this.helloBean = helloBean;
//    }

public static void sayGreeting(){
    helloBean.sayHello();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GreetingBean.sayGreeting();
}
}
```

The HelloBean class is as follows.

```
public class HelloBean {

public void sayHello(){
    System.out.println("Hello user");
}
}
```

On execution I got a null pointer exception which is obvious as helloBean is not initialised. According to what I understood from the tutorial @Inject is supposed to take care of that. I feel that I have to do something more to  make this work but I could not find any reference. Can someone help me in this matter.

Comment: You're running your app with a regular old ``main``. You need a CDI container that takes care care of dependency injection...

Comment: the article is about Java EE and you are writing a stand alone program. That is 2 different topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#_cdi_se_module) if you want to use CDI with a standard Java application. (This is using the reference CDI implementation, Weld)